# Is it possible to get a divorce on documents completed online?

Tags: united-kingdom, divorce, family

For a long time I avoided meeting my husband because I didn't want to divorce him. I think that without my consent, he cannot start a divorce proceedings. However, yesterday he brought me ready-made documents and said that my unwillingness to get a divorce now doesn't bother him. I can not believe this! Doesn't he need my consent? How, then, should the common property be divided?

Comment: In England and Wales, there are different rules for contested vs uncontested divorces. In particular, there are different durations for which you have to stay separated before a court will accept the divorce. Deserting your husband for 2 years would give him the right to divorce. You cannot keep someone in a marriage against their will, your consent to the divorce doesn't directly matter.

Comment: If you haven't been with your husband for years, you may not have a claim to "common property". This all depends on what happens in court. You can choose to participate in your divorce or not, but it will happen either way.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The Federal Circuit Court has jurisdiction over [divorce](http://www.federalcircuitcourt.gov.au/wps/wcm/connect/fccweb/how-do-i/divorce/apply-for-a-divorce/apply-for-divorce) under that *Family Law Act 1975*.

> You can apply for a divorce by yourself (sole application) or together with the other party to the marriage (joint application). The same online application is used for both sole and joint applications.

> If you make a sole application, you are known as the applicant and the other party is known as the respondent. Only you as the applicant are required to sign the Affidavit for eFiling Application (Divorce). The respondent does not need to sign the Affidavit for eFiling Application (Divorce) however you do need to serve the application on the respondent. For more information see How do I serve a divorce.

> Court attendance is not required if there are no children of the marriage.

> Court attendance is required if there are children under the age of 18 years.